# If $(G:H)$ and $|H|=n$ are relatively prime,$H$ is a normal subgroup then if $x \in G$ and $x^n = e$ then $x \in H $

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

This is a question from Herstein, 2.7.
If I try a proof by contradiction, I can assume that $x$ $\notin H$.
$\space$ Let $o(H) = n$ and $o(G/N) = m/n$ where $o(G)=m$

Hence $xH$ is an element of $G/H$ $\space \space \space$ ($H$ is a normal subgroup)

Then as the $o(G/H) = m/n$, $(xH)^{m/n} = x^{m/n}H = H$
$\Rightarrow x^{m/n} \in H$

Also, by the question we have, $x^n =e$ so, $o(x)/n$

Also, since $o(G)=m \Rightarrow x^m=e \Rightarrow o(x)/m $

This is all i could figure out. I am not being able to piece together this information to get my proof. I don't even know where to go from here. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Third sentence should be "$o(G/H)$", not $o(G/N)$; there is no $N$.

Comment: You  want to show that, as an element of $G/H$, $xH$ has order dividing $n$ and $m/n$.

Comment: With $d=m/n$, do you know that there are integers $r,s$ such that $rd+sn=1$ because $d,n$ are coprime? What happens if you raise $x$ to $rd+sn$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to argue by contradiction. Consider $xH$ in $G/H$. Let $k=|G/H|$. Now verify that $xH$ has order dividing both $k$ and $n$ in $G/H$, hence has order dividing $\gcd(k,n)$.

Comment: Since $x^n =e$, $(xH)^n = H \Rightarrow o(xH)/n$ and from @stackex33 's hint (thank you!) that would mean order of xH is 1. So x would have to be an element of H! This is it right?

Comment: @ali: There is no need to muck about with fractions, but essentially yes. Just note that $(xH)^n=H$ and that $(xH)^k=H$ (where $k=[G:H]$), so $o(xH)|\gcd(k,n)=1$.